# aws dynamo db search

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have the following keys.txt

```
{
    "test": {"BOOL": true}
}
```

I run the following command
aws dynamodb get-item --table-name marvel-users-prod --key file://keys.json

but its not returning the items that match the key/value. What am I doing wrong?

I get the error

```
A client error (ValidationException) occurred when calling the GetItem operation: The provided key element does not match the schema
```

I tried using the GUI but the scan stopped.

Comment: May I know whether the answer was helpful? If yes, could you please accept the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Get-item** can be used to get the data by primary key. The DynamoDB hash key can't be BOOL type.

> The get-item operation returns a set of attributes for the item with
>   the given primary key. If there is no matching item, get-item does not
>   return any data.

**Create Table Attribute Types:-**

> "AttributeType": "S"|"N"|"B"

Also, I assume that the boolean attribute that you would like to filter is one of the attributes in the Dynamodb table. You may need to scan the table if you don't include the hash key in the filter criteria.

**Scan command:-**

"interested" - is my BOOL attribute name

:a - Attribute value placeholder. The value is present in the JSON file

```
aws dynamodb scan --table-name autotable --filter-expression "interested = :a" --expression-attribute-values file://scan-movies.json
```

**Scan Movies JSON file:-**

```
{
  ":a": {"BOOL" : true}
}
```